# Código jQuery funciona em 'http'://jsfiddle.net porém não funciona em 'https'://jsfiddle.net

Tags: jquery, html5, jsfiddle

Montei o código jQuery no jsFiddle.net para testar e funcionou corretamente, contudo ao enviar o link, fornecido pelo jsFiddle, com **https**, o código parou de funcionar.

Alguém sabe explicar o motivo? Estou usando o Google Chrome versão 42

Código funcionando:

> [jsFiddle - HTTP](http://jsfiddle.net/evertramos/ag9p2tvj/6/)

O mesmo código no jsFiddle com o **https** (não está funcionando):

> [jsFiddle - HTTPS](https://jsfiddle.net/evertramos/ag9p2tvj/6/)

Obrigado!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quando carregas a página em HTTPS o jsFiddle quer garantir que o conteúdo carregado também está em HTTPS, mas o código externo que estás a carregar está em HTTP. Então o jsFiddle não carrega esse código e daí o "não funcionar".

Se abrires a consola vês alguns erros. Um deles `$(...).mask is not a function` é porque o método não existe uma vez que o ficheiro externo não foi carregado. O outro é exatamente a explicar o que escreví em cima:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/evertramos/ag9p2tvj/6/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Se mudares essa referência externa para HTTPS, ficando o url: `https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js`, então já vai funcionar.

Ou [como o @OnoSendai referiu:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63540/c%C3%B3digo-jquery-funciona-em-http-jsfiddle-net-por%C3%A9m-n%C3%A3o-funciona-em-https/63543#comment129817_63543) "se a referência for alterada para `//igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js` (ignorando o protocolo) o código funcionará intependente do ambiente; o browser tentará resolver o protocolo correto".

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbbxg3m6/

Comment: Legal @Sergio, obrigado!

Comment: @Evert apenas complementando a resposta (correta) de Sergio - se a referência for alterada para `//igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js` (ignorando o protocolo) o código funcionará intependente do ambiente; o browser tentará resolver o protocolo correto.

Comment: @OnoSendai bem visto.

Comment: @OnoSendai bacana! Apesar de mesmo estando com https funcionar em ambiente http, ao menos no Fiddle, creio que seja a melhor opção OnoSendai. Obrigado pela complementação.